# What frees the `.init.ramfs` image after it is unpacked into the `rootfs`?

Tags: linux-kernel, initramfs, arch-arm

Under the old `initrd` system, Linux used to free the `initrd` image. This was traced on the console:

```
 Freeing initrd memory: xxxxk freed.
```

What this referred to was actually releasing the memory occupied by the original compressed image. The live, mounted filesystem was released via unmounting (via `pivot_root` to the replacement root).

Under `initramfs`, the filesystem is released by a recursive removal using some utility like `switch_root`, and is never unmounted. I understand that, but where is the original image (the compressed `.cpio` archive) freed?

I'm looking at `init/initramfs.c (populate_rootfs)` and see that in fact `initramfs` can unpack data from either `__initramfs_start` or `initrd_start`, or even both!  The `initrd` area is freed by `free_initrd()`, but there is no logic here for doing the analogous freeing for the memory starting at `__initramfs_start`.

Can someone shed some light on how this memory is freed? Or else confirm that it's not freed? Is it in a section that gets discarded along with other unused memory?

I added some diagnostics which show that `__initramfs_start` is outside of the unused memory that is freed. This is on an ARM embedded system:

```
[    1.241857] Freeing unused kernel memory: 3240K [c0c01000, c0f2b000)
[    1.241874] Initramfs image starts at: e7fddef0
```

But then, if I look at the linker script, I see that the `INITRAMFS` **is** placed between `__init_start` and `__init_end` symbols, so maybe this discrepancy is due to some run-time relocation? The size is about right: the original compressed image is 2958550 bytes, which could reasonably account for the bulk of this reported 3240K.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've confirmed that the memory gets freed by the following experiment. I added a few megabytes of random junk into the `initramfs`, built the kernel and booted. The `Freeing unused kernel memory` reported size increased by about the size of that junk. Furthermore, this bloat made no difference to the free memory seen just after boot via `free` and `/proc/meminfo`.